# UserForm not coming up after button click

Tags: excel, vba

I created two new user forms for a worksheet. After I made them I added two buttons to the excel page. Then I set up a module and put in

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Missing.Show
End Sub
```

Now that I assigned the macro to the button, when I click the button I get an "object required" error.  Why is this, and what can I do to make th buttons actually open the usr form if the above is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out the problem.  It actually had nothing to do with the button itself.  `Missing.Show` works perfectly fine.  It was actually a problem with the form initialization; at some point I changed the initialization to

```
Private Sub Missing_Initialize()
    TextBox.Value = ""
End Sub
```

when I actually should have left it at

```
Private Sub UserForm2_Initialize()
    TextBox.Value = ""
End Sub
```

So, apparently, even though the error was always taking me to the button code, it was actually the form's initialization that was causing the fuss.  Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Private Sub Missing_Click()
Load Missing
Missing.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: When I do this I get "Compile Error: Expected Function or Variable"

Comment: @Jon In that case you have a form button, rather than an activex control button. Create a function instead of a sub.

Comment: When I use an activex control button in the worksheet I get a "424: Object Required" error.

Comment: Your form is definitely called missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4517/discussion-between-remou-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are outside the form's (class) module, VBA has no idea what "Missing" refers to. You have to instantiate it first.

```
Dim frm As Missing

Set frm = New Missing

Missing.Show
```

And if I may add, it's none of my business but "Missing.Show" could be confusing. I would avoid the use of variables that look like keywords.

Comment: This is still giving me a "424: Object required" error on the middle line

Comment: I tried this using controls from both the Forms and Controls toolbars, in Excel 2003. The button from the Control Toolbox is placed on Sheet1 and the code is in the Sheet1 module. The button from the Forms Toolbar is also placed on Sheet1 and the code is in a standard module in the same project/workbook. It worked as expected. You need to clearly explain in detail where the buttons are, what type they are and where the code is going.

Comment: I have tried both answers above with both types of buttons (form control and activex).  I have tried to put the code in a module of its own, and it always gives the 424 error at either the "load" line or the "set" line.  I have also tried putting both versions of the answers above into the sheet module itself, and I still get the 424 error in the same exact spot.  I understand it should be coming up easily, but it simply is not pulling the userforms.  I have no idea where to go with it at this point.